# Div within div to show outside the div

Tags: html, css, position

I cant seem to be able to do this with relative and absolute positioning like I have with other things, but what I want to achieve is to have a div, with another div within it, however this inner div must appear outside the outer div on screen.

```
<div class="OuterDiv">
    <span>Other things</span>
    <div class="InnerDiv">
        <span>Inner content</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

[image: div placements]

EDIT : OK, so this I think is more complex than people are thinking. Using position relative and absolute I have already gotten other things on my page to work. What I have when I try this problem using positioning is

[image: Second Description]

And then disappears completely when moved far enough outside of the outer div

More of my code,

```
<div class="Item Menu Active" style="display: inline-block;">
<div class="ItemList" style="left: -315.859375px;">
    <div class="Item" style="display: inline-block;">
        <span>N</span>
        <div class="ItemList">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="Item" style="display: inline-block;">
        <span>O</span>
        <div class="ItemList">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="Item" style="display: inline-block;">
        <span>P</span>
        <div class="ItemList">
            <div class="Item ClickItem">
                <span>p1</span>
                <div class="ItemList">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="Item" style="display: inline-block;">
        <span>Q</span>
        <div class="ItemList">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>

.Item {
display: inline-block;
position: relative;
white-space: nowrap;
padding: 5px 10px 5px 10px;
cursor: pointer;
}
.ItemList {
display: none;
z-index: 1;
min-width: 75px;
position: absolute;
top: 100%;
left: 0px;
overflow-y: scroll;
overflow-x: hidden;
white-space: initial;
padding: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
background-color: white;
border: 1px solid black;
cursor: default;
}
```

EDIT 2 : Yes `overflow:visible` was my problem, issue is that overwrites the `overflow-x` and `overflow-y` that I am already using on the .ItemList for vertical scrolling on smaller screens. Any further suggestions?

Comment: Please include the CSS you've attempted.

Comment: It's very simple: http://jsfiddle.net/45wo2mz3/

Answer (score 1):

You could position `absolute`ly the inner `div` with the respect to the `body` as follows:

```css
* { box-sizing: border-box; }

html {
  height: 100% }

body {
  position: relative;
  padding: 10px;
  min-height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  border: 10px solid red; }

.OuterDiv {
  width: 50%;
  border: 10px solid green; }

.InnerDiv {
  position: absolute;
  width: 20%;
  right: 10px;
  border: 10px solid blue; }
```

```html
<div class="OuterDiv">
    <span>Other things</span>
    <div class="InnerDiv">
        <span>Inner content</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Note that in this case you must ensure that the `body` is high enough to contain the absolutely positioned *inner* div.

Answer (score 0):

I feel like you shouldn't be structuring your HTML this way if this is the desired result: why not just have the inner div placed outside the parent's hierarchy? Either way, something like this should work:

```
<body>
    <div id="outer">
        <div id="inner">
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

And CSS

```
#body
{
    position:relative;
}
#inner
{
    position:absolute;
    right:0;
    top:30px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `position` rule to set your elements to display within each-other.

```css
#Outer {
 position: relative;
 width: 300px;
 height: 180px;
 border: 3px solid red;
}

#Inner {
 position: absolute;
 width:  50%;
 height: 50%;
 border: 3px solid blue;
 margin: 5%;
}
```

```html
<div id="Outer">
  <div id="Inner"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Edit:
**It disappears because of overflow-x: hidden;**

Previous:
http://jsfiddle.net/1k1rfrn3/ 
You should avoid hacking your DOM with CSS.

```
.OuterDiv{
border-style: solid;
border-width: 5px;
color: blue;
position:absolute;
overflow: visible;
}
.InnerDiv{
border-style: solid;
border-width: 5px;
color:red;
position:absolute;
left:500px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this out :

```css
.OuterDiv{ position:relative; width:80px; height:80px; border:5px solid green }
.InnerDiv{ position:absolute; top:0; right:-100px; width:80px; height:80px; border:5px solid red }
```

```html
<div class="OuterDiv">
    <span>Other things</span>
    <div class="InnerDiv">
        <span>Inner content</span>
    </div>
</div>
```